# Colors weave into a spire of flames

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vAhPeqlODg

Ok—jig's up—this one's only related to smash in name, but it'll give you something to burn your time with while you wait 'til December 7th

Given a color string `s` of form `#rgb`(in hex, so #000000 to #ffffff, dont worry about the three digit ones: <s>#123</s>) you must average the rgb values, and turn it into a **flame** color(heyy see what I did there?)

to turn an average hex number `n`(0-255) to a "flame color"
you must return a string `#rgb`with:

`r = n`

`g = n - 144`(the 144 is decimal, hex is 0x90) or if `n - 144` is <0, then g = 0

`b = 0`

Given this is smash, we have to have items off. So no using arrays, maps, or sets(don't get into semantics about how strings are just abstracted arrays, I don't want to hear it)

1. [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are prohibited
2. Acceptable answers: a function which takes input through one input
   string and returns one output string
3. If the input string doesn't match the requirements provided above,
   your code MUST error out(doesn't matter what kind of Exception or
   Error)
4. This is code-golf, so the shortest(valid)answer (in each language)
   wins!
5. Bonus points for a one-liner  (Not really tho, just cool points)

Comment: Hiya, Michael! This is a nice idea for a challenge. I want to let you know that our community has accumulated some [Things to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/16596) over time, and among them are [“answer must be a function”](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/3852), [“do X without Y”](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/3852) (i.e. banning arrays and maps) and [input validation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16596/3852).

Comment: You can read some pretty good cases under those links for why we've found those things generally detract from a challenge, or keep certain languages from competing. (Often they are “loaded” in a way that makes them not even make sense for all languages: for example, there's _literally_ no distinction between strings and arrays of characters in many languages. Either way, it's such a blurred line, and all the bickering hasn't ever been worth it.)

Comment: I suggest you allow answers to perform I/O in whatever manner is convenient, with whatever tools they need, and I suggest you allow answers to assume that the input string they're given is always valid. That way, the “heart” of the task (the operation on `#rrggbb` strings) can really shine!

Comment: That said, the only unclear portion of the task I can put my finger on is whether we should compute `(r+g+b)/3` rounding down to zero, or to the nearest integer. It's also always a good idea to include some test cases: example inputs along with the expected output. (In the future, the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) can help you iron this stuff out in advance. It's really nifty!) Ack, I hope that all isn't too overwhelming! Welcome to PPCG. ^^

Comment: I find the description semi-incoherent. Has it lost a paragraph or two of background / context?

Comment: @Peter Taylor have you seen the new Nintendo direct?

Comment: No. Perhaps you could add an introductory paragraph explaining the relevance and linking to further information.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 108 bytes

```perl6
{[$!=S/^\#(<[\d|A..F]>**2)**3$/{"#"~[~] ((sum("0x"X~$0)/3 X-0,144,255)Xmax 0)>>.fmt("%02x")}/,1/0][$! eq$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc3PCoIwAIDxe0@x5optmJvzT0UprEMv0EXQFUJKhwaVRorpqy8vQXT8fpfvVjyuodEtmJcgAqZL0TQ6sGNm4W2and/ScfYqplQQSj3EOmjBIR0UwLh6agx5A5MBccI8kCy47fq@LYKAJDpvACdx7JS6xnDGRQNJz2yXcTUOQHFHJ9WbKm9BiaHFXeH5ASSbyVfC5Wotd78i5Z@8Lnk9pvkA)

Anonymous code block that takes a string and returns a string if it is in a valid format, or a div by zero error otherwise. Though I'm not really sure how you're defining `arrays`,`maps` or `sets`, since my code uses sequences (`Seq`) and `Match`s...

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 96 bytes

```
func[s][c: hex-to-rgb do s n: c/1 + c/2 + c/3 / 3
to-hex/size n * 65536 +(256 * max 0 n - 144)6]
```

### Note:

It doesn't work in TIO (doesn't recognize `hex-to-rgb`- maybe it is not implemented for  Linux yet).

### Tests within the Red console:

(first 3 taken from Jo King - thanks!):

```
>> print f "#012345"
#230000
>> print f "#6789AB"
#890000
>> print f "#AA89AB"
#9F0F00
>> print f "code golf"
*** Script Error: code has no value
*** Where: do
*** Stack: f hex-to-rgb
```